# Namespace output with XSLT 1.0 causing problems

Tags: xml, xslt, namespaces, xslt-1.0

I'm using XSLT 1.0 to transform some XML.

I'm not quite sure the best way to explain this, so will use some examples.

My input XML contains a specialization, using the xsi:type declaration. See the Payload node:

```
<ns0:RootNode xmlns:ns0="namespace1" xmlns:ns1="namespace2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ns0:Payload xsi:type="ns1:SpecialPayload">
    <ns1:InnerNode>Hello</ns1:InnerNode>
  </ns0:Payload>
</ns0:RootNode>
```

When I send this through my XSLT (let's assume a 1 to 1 copy), I get the following output

```
<ns0:RootNode xmlns:ns0="namespace1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ns0:Payload xsi:type="ns1:SpecialPayload">
    <ns1:InnerNode xmlns:ns1="namespace2">Hello</ns1:InnerNode>
  </ns0:Payload>
</ns0:RootNode>
```

Notice the ns1 namespace has been attached to the individual nodes within the payload node. In most cases this would be fine, however I need that declaration to happen earlier, i.e. on the root node, as it makes the xsi:type definition on the payload node invalid, because at this point the serializer does not know about the ns1 namespace, which prevents correct parsing downstream.

What can I do to force this namespace to be output a little earlier?

Edited XSLT Code:

```
  <!-- Replace The ESBMessage node with the SOAP method -->
  <xsl:template match="s1:ESBMessage" mode="copy">
    <s0:SendESBMessage>
      <s0:msg>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*" mode="copy"/>
      </s0:msg>
    </s0:SendESBMessage>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Generic Copy -->
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="copy">
    <xsl:element name="{name(.)}" namespace="{namespace-uri(.)}">
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="copy"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
```

Comment: As you can see from my answer, your question is missing important and necessary information. Please, provide the minimal code example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Hi Dimitre, I have added a code example as requested. I'm just looking through your code to see if there is something there i'm missing. Thank you!

Comment: Your rule isn't an identity rule at all. You are saying: *When matching an element in `copy` mode, create an element with the same QName and the same namespace URI. Add as content a copy of attribute childs and apply templates to node childs in `copy` mode.* So, basicaly your are stripping in-scope namespaces, something that doesn't happend when ussing `xsl:copy` instruction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Notice the ns1 namespace has been
>   attached to the individual nodes
>   within the payload node. In most cases
>   this would be fine, however I need
>   that declaration to happen earlier,
>   i.e. on the root node, as it makes the
>   xsi:type definition on the payload
>   node invalid, because at this point
>   the serializer does not know about the
>   ns1 namespace, which prevents correct
>   parsing downstream.
>
> What can I do to force this namespace
>   to be output a little earlier?

**You can do something very simple: show us your code**!

Your statement that a "simple copy" loses one of the namespaces of the top node, is not true for the following two "simple copies":

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<ns0:RootNode xmlns:ns0="namespace1" xmlns:ns1="namespace2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ns0:Payload xsi:type="ns1:SpecialPayload">
    <ns1:InnerNode>Hello</ns1:InnerNode>
  </ns0:Payload>
</ns0:RootNode>
```

**the result is identical**:

```
<ns0:RootNode xmlns:ns0="namespace1" xmlns:ns1="namespace2" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <ns0:Payload xsi:type="ns1:SpecialPayload">
    <ns1:InnerNode>Hello</ns1:InnerNode>
  </ns0:Payload>
</ns0:RootNode>
```

**Here is the second "simple copy":**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**the result is again identical to the source XML document**.

Comment: Dimitre, I replaced my copy code with yours and it worked. Why is it that the * semantics does not do the same as node()?@*?

Comment: @themistry: I cannot answer your question without having seen your code. I *guess* that you are copying element nodes, but somehow you are not copying namespace nodes. This may happen if you are using the `<xsl:element>` instruction. Anyway, your unshown code, obviously isn't a "copy" transformation.